# Set Snap Mode with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to set **snap mode** within QGIS plugin.

So far, I have tried:

```
QgsSnappingUtils().setSnapToMapMode(QgsSnappingUtils.SnapAdvanced)
```

and

```
QgsSnappingUtils().setSnapToMapMode(2)
```

without success. 
QGIS Snapping options (Settings>>Snapping Options...) continue with:
 Snapping mode = Current layer

Any hint? (Using v 2.14.0)

Comment: Not sure if this post might help? [How to enable the snapping for a layer with the tolerance value with python programming](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135800/how-to-enable-the-snapping-for-a-layer-with-the-tolerance-value-with-python-prog)

Comment: @Joseph No, it does not help... setSnapSettingsForLayer() works fine and I can define snapping tolerance for each layer without problem. I can't "jump" to Advanced mode with python (setSnapToMapMode).

Comment: Related: QgsSnappingUtils().snapToMapMode() always returns 0 even if I change snap mode with the GUI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution to that. As it seems to be impossible to access snapping mode from the QgsProject, I try to access it from the QgsInterface.
This works for me in python Console:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDockWidget, QDialog,QComboBox

iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options').findChild(QDialog).findChild(QComboBox,'mSnapModeComboBox').setCurrentIndex(0)
```

Change the current Index to fit to your needs:
0 = current layer
1 = all layers
2 = advanced

then you can set your snapping's settings with `QgsProject.instance().setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(),...)`

Answer (score 2):

I fund the what you shearch here: [QGIS doesn't update some snapping options from Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200735/qgis-doesnt-update-some-snapping-options-from-python/200856)

```
proj = QgsProject.instance()
proj.writeEntry('Digitizing', 'SnappingMode', 'advanced') 
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
proj.setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(), True, 0, 1, 30, True)
```