# Enable snapping options in QGIS-2.18 plugin using Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, snapping

I have a custom plugin to place point feature on another point feature.
So i want to enable/activate snapping options before i place that feature in my QGIS application using python.

So far i tried lot of answers that i found here

[Set Snap Mode with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195760/set-snap-mode-with-pyqgis)

[enable snapping in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200735/qgis-doesnt-update-some-snapping-options-from-python/200856)

but none works for me ...

Anyone help me please ..!!!

Comment: can anyone suggest me please

Comment: i dont know if it works but, is it possible to do like this way..!!!